# How to dynamically allocate a string using function?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, dynamic

I am trying to allocate a dynamic string by accepting it from user. I want to do it using a function. I am trying to implement the following code, but it is not working properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int string(char *str)
{
    char c; 
    int i=0,j=1;
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter String : ");
    while(c!='\n')
    {
        c = getc(stdin);     //read the input from keyboard standard input
        //re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        *str = (char*)realloc(str,j*sizeof(char));
        *str[i] = c;  //store read character by making pointer point to c
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    str[i]='\0';   //at the end append null character to mark end of string
    printf("\nThe entered string is : %s",str);
    return j;    
}


int main()
{
    int len;
    char *str=NULL;
    len=string(str);
    printf("\nThe entered string is : %s and it is of %d length.",str,len);
    free(str);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why 2 stars when passing pointer to a string to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534878/why-2-stars-when-passing-pointer-to-a-string-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of issues:

1. memory size is one too small.
2. `while(c!='\n')` first test `c` even though it is uninitialized.
3. `string()` should pass the address of a `char *` as in `string(char **)`
4. Better to use `size_t` rather than `int` when working with `strlen()`.

Minor:

5. EOF is not detected.  Use `int c` rather than `char c` to aid in detection.
6. Certainly inefficient to `realloc()` each loop.
7. Casting of `malloc()/realloc()` unnecessary.
8. Good to check for out-of-memory.
9. Use `int main(void)` rather than `int main()` for portability.

   ```
   size_t string(char **str) {
     assert(str);
     int c; 
     size_t i = 0;
     size_t size = 0;
     *str = NULL;

     printf("Enter String : ");
     while((c = getc(stdin)) !='\n' && c != EOF) {
       if (i == size) {
         size *= 2 + 1;         // double the size each time
         *str = realloc(*str, size);
         assert(*str);
       }
       (*str)[i] = c;           // store read character by making pointer point to c
       i++;
     }
     *str = realloc(*str, i+1); // right-size the string
     assert(*str);
     (*str)[i] = '\0';          // at the end append null character to mark end 
     printf("\nThe entered string is : %s",*str);
     return i;    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a referejce to a pointer (`int string(char **str)`) because you're changing the value of `str` inside the function.

In `main` you should call `string(&str)`